# remove icon from theme in android?

Tags: android, icons, android-theme

I have a global theme with icon and application name . There is a requirement wherein a particular activity does not have icon . I did not find any methods to remove the icon on top of action bar for that particular activity alone . Thanks inadvance

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled%28boolean%29

Comment: awesome , exactly what i was looking for :)